# jQueryで画像の表示・非表示を切り替える方法について

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

はじめまして！
HTML、Javascript、jQueryの初心者です。
以下のプログラムで、
最初にimage/1.jpgが表示され
マウスをクリックすると
image/2-1.jpgが表示されるようにしたいのですが
最初の画面から変わりません…

３時間ほどサイトを見てあれこれ試したのですがだめでした。。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!--ボタンの画像表示-->
    <p class="button">
    <img style="width: 100%;" src="image/1.jpg" alt="ボタン"  >
    </p>

    <pp class="note">
    <img style="width: 100%;" src="image/2-1.jpg" alt="ノート" >
    </pp>

    <!--ボタンを押したら選択画面-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $('p').click(function(){
                $('pp').show();
            });
        });  
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: なぜHTMLには存在しない`pp`なんてタグを使われているのでしょうか?

Comment: tanalab2様、OOPer様　ご回答いただきまことにありがとうございます！！急にホームページを作成することになり、デザインはできたのですがプログラミングがよくわからず、ネットで調べつつツギハギの知識しかない状態なのです…

Comment: 基礎のできていない状態での質問をしてしまい大変申し訳ございませんでした…

Comment: @user29323 さん、tanalab2 さんの回答で無事に問題が解決できたと言うことなら、回答の「承認」をしてください。ちなみに存在しないタグを使うと言うのは挙動が予測できなくなるので、やめた方が良いですね。それと tanalab2 さんの回答へのコメントのような内容はタイトルや本文に含めるようにしてください。ちなみに「【初心者です】」のように、回答者に「どの程度わかっててどこからがわからないのか」のヒントを全く与えないような内容は不要です。その分自分のしたいこと、どううまくいかないのかをきちんとタイトルや本文に含めるようにしてください。質問内容については、たとえ初歩的に思われることでも、他の初学者のために残しておくと有用なことも多くあります。それなりの時間調べてみてダメだったのなら、臆せずご質問していただいても良いと思います。

Comment: @tanalab2 さん、どんな人にでも知らないことはあり、そのための質問サイトです。質問者のレベルで質問してよいかどうかを決めるのではなく、質問が質問になっているかで決める方が誠実だと私は思っています。また、このご質問は疑問点が分かりやすく、1つの質問としてちゃんと成り立っているとも思います。質問すること自体を拒否するのではなく、ご回答の中で更なる情報として入門書やチュートリアルをオススメ頂くのは如何でしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん。すみません。コメントの書き方がよくなかったですね。今後、質問される方にも悪影響があるかもしれないので、削除しておきます。

Comment: @user29323 さん、ご質問ありがとうございました！　一点確認したいのですが、`<pp>` のようなタグを用意したのは、そのままだと一番目の `<p>` タグと区別が付かないからでしょうか。もしそうであれば、そのようなことを実現するために id や class などの仕組みが用意されていますので、検索キーワードとして使えると思います。`jquery id` などでお調べください。

Comment: OOPer様>今、少しずつ完成形に近付いているところですので、解決できましたら「承認」させていただきます。

Comment: nekketsuuu様>はい。仰るとおり<p>と<pp>で区別したかったのです。｢jquery id｣で検索して見ます。アドバイス真にありがとうございます。

Comment: 皆様>一日中、画像作成とHTML,jQueryをやっていたので疲れが出てきてしまいました…続きは明日がんばります。できましたらご報告させていただきます。真にありがとうございました！！

Comment: 皆様>おかげさまで無事表示することができました！とても嬉しいです。まだ道のりは長いですが、一つづつクリアしていきます。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 最初にimage/1.jpgが表示され 
>   マウスをクリックすると 
>   image/2-1.jpgが表示されるようにしたいのですが

上記を以下のように解釈しました。

1. 画面初回表示時、`image/1.jpg`は表示、`image/2-1.jpg`は非表示
2. `image/1.jpg`をクリック時、`image/1.jpg`は非表示、`image/2-1.jpg`は表示
3. `image/2-1.jpg`をクリック時、`image/1.jpg`は表示、`image/2-1.jpg`は非表示

jqueryのみで対応するのであれば、以下の実装はいかがでしょうか。

```js
$(function() {
  // 画面初回表示時
  $('p.note').hide();
  
  // image/1.jpgをクリック時の処理
  $('p.button').click(function(){
    // 'p.note'を表示
    $('p.note').show();
    // 'p.button'を非表示
    $(this).hide();
  });
  
  // image/2-1.jpgをクリック時の処理
  $('p.note').click(function() {
    // 'p.button'を表示
    $('p.button').show();
    // 'p.note'を非表示
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--ボタンの画像表示-->
<p class="button">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/600x100/333/ffffff&text=image/1.jpg" alt="ボタン"  >
</p>

<p class="note">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/600x100/006600/ffffff&text=image/2-1.jpg" alt="ノート" >
</p>
```

Comment: tanalab2様さっそくのご対応まことにありがとうございます！！じつは、image/1,jpgが画面全体に表示されている状態で、クリックするとimage/2-1.jpgが画面全体に表示されるようにしたかったのです。言葉足らずで申し訳ございません。

Comment: @user29323 クリックするとimage/2-1.jpgが表示されるように修正しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: tanalab2様できました！おかげさまで無事表示がされました。感謝の気持ちでいっぱいです。まだ道のりは長いですが、一つづつクリアしていきます。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。